# Client flow login for Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am looking for sdk that can help me do the client flow login in my Xamarin app(shared assets with forms UI) for Facebook and LinkedIn for iOS and android. I've got it working using Xamarin.Auth server flow but having hard time in client flow. 
For facebook, I tried Xamarin Android Facebook, Xamarin iOS Facebook and cross platform facebook sdk by outercurve foundation. The official xamarin facebook sdk's are in very bad shape, don't work and no documentation has been provided as well. I couldn't find any for LinkedIn though.
My main objective is to use facebook and linkedin app to do the authentication to provide better user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually worked with official Xamarin Facebook SDK's for facebook for android and iOS. [This blog post from James Montemagno](https://blog.xamarin.com/native-android-facebook-authentication-azure-app-service/) came in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Auth0. They have a reasonable SDK and they support a large number of different Social Authentication providers including Facebook and LinkedIn. Their authentication service isn't free once you reach critical mass, but it's great to have the whole authentication aspect handled for you. Check it out at http://www.auth0.com

Comment: I have tried Auth0 as well. I am not sure if it does what I am looking for which is authentication using facebook and linkedin's app which is installed on device. It does it with webview which I am trying to avoid.